# hardcoding debug buttons MVC Razor 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making a website and i have created a login  that works, and i need to test other portions of the website most of them require a login to proceed . I am trying to save some time by creating a debug button that will auto log me in so i don't need to write my username and password each time.

The only thing is, i don't know how to hard code values into a value

So this is my Login method

```
 @if (Session["LoginStatus"] == null)
    {
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions 
      {
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       LoadingElementId = "Loading-Login",
       UpdateTargetId = "popover_footer",
       OnSuccess = "login_Successful"
      },new {id = "popover-list-item"}))
      {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           ... some divs
               @Html.Label("User Name")
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100%;" })

               @Html.Label("Password")
               @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100%;" })

               @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.RememberMe)<label> Remeber Me </label>
             ... some more divs
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">GO</button>
       ...even more divs
  }
```

What i would like to do is something along the lines of

```
@model.Username = "AdminLogin"
@model.Password = "Password"
```

I have tried using @Html.EditorFor() and Editor, but they didn't assign values.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. First time you log in the browser will offer to remember credentials so you don't have to write them agan, there is no need to such a button. Am I missing somethig?

Comment: every time I stop the iisExpress it automatically clears my cookies from the site, so no. i need to log in each time

Comment: you can use IIS instead of iisExpress but I understand the problem now.

Comment: I will eventually use IIS when i am closer to completion, i just started this site ha ha

Comment: You risk to forgot to delete this kind of hacks and pushing them to production. I recomend you another alternative: form autofill browser extensions. This is a sample for chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/junkfill/cajejbcjfkhgmfbapmhopccephhjedeb?hl=en. I've used one for firefox and the worked really well.

Comment: that i understand, But its only a partial debug. Because i have admin-login, user-login, and VIP-login. so i still need to swtich between the test accounts. so auto fill will only work some of the time

Comment: I would bake it into the dll and not in the html itself. Overall though this idea is ripe for abuse